# Working with staging server and production server - can they share the same Assets locations?

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I have 3 installations of my website: beta, demo, and production. Template and functionality changes are made on beta, content is entered on demo and everything moves to production as it is approved.

We are using Assets for all of our, um, assets (images, audio files, etc.). I would like to move everything to Amazon S3 and have all 3 installations point to one place so that I don't have to have 3 copies of everything. Is this possible? In order to update the database, right now, I back up the version on demo and move it to the other locations. So that would have the index information, right?

If anyone has any other ideas on the best way to store assets in one location for use in multiple installations, I would appreciate hearing about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a client that has a similar setup with Assets and S3 and it works without issues, content created on local, dev, staging has no issues being added to the live site or any combination of that.

I also have a client that has dev, staging and live instances on the same server and I have the upload path folders symalinked to the live for dev and staging. Which works without issues. In this case usually the live DB is transfer to the dev and staging DB to test out new features or troubleshoot/change templates with real content from the live site.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad approach; I'm using it on a large project now and we haven't had too many issues.

In our setup, development/staging share the same database but have their own file system for templates/snippets/EE.